# How to SSR the translations using remix-i18next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next, remix, remix.run

I have a remix project and I would like to server-side render all the translations. I am using remix-i18next. However, using the following code the translations doesn't show initially, it shows all the keys first and then it loads the translations:

```
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

export default function A() {
  let { t } = useTranslation("a");
  return <h1>{t("greeting")}</h1>;
}
```

I know I can do the following:

```
import { useLoaderData } from "@remix-run/react";

import i18next from "~/i18next.server";

export async function loader({ request }) {
  const t = await i18next.getFixedT(request, "a");
  return t("greeting");
}

export default function A() {
  const greeting = useLoaderData();
  return <h1>{greeting}</h1>;
}
```

However, I don't want to use the loader to load all the translations from there since it introduces a lot of boilerplate and you can't use things like the Trans component. I would like to know if there is an alternative.

Comment: Did you find out how to do this?